# How to delete a cell if it contains one (or more) Chr(10) characters, but no other characters?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small script that sort of does what I need it to do, but I'm afraid at some point there will be more than 4 characters in a cell and I don't want to delete it.  The logic that I want to employ is as follows:

If any cell in BB1:BB10 contains ONLY Chr(10) then move the contents of the cells below up one cell.  Something like this

```
Public Sub CheckHisMethod()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Value = Chr(10) Then        ' or =vblf or =chr$(10)
            Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

But...I don't want to delete the Chr(10) from each cell, I only want to delete the cell, and move the cell below up one cell, if the cell contains ONLY Chr(10).  How can I do that?

Comment: What's the problem with your solution?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little hard to explain.  I have cells in an array with 1, 2, 3, 4, or more Chr(10) characters.  I have cells with text and Chr(10) characters.  I want to delete cells with ONLY 1, 2, 3, 4, or more Chr(10) characters.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Probably a pair of screenshots would help. E.g. Input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following.  It removes all `CHR(10)` and then it checks if the length of the resulting string is 0, meaning all characters in the cell are `CHR(10)`.

```
Public Sub CheckHisMethod()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Replace(Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Value,Chr(10),"")) = 0 Then        ' or =vblf or =chr$(10)
            Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use a regular expression for this - it will likely be much faster than other string manipulations:

```
'Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
Public Sub CheckHisMethod()
    Dim i As Integer
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "^[\n]+$"
        .MultiLine = True
        For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
            If .Test(Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Value) Then
                Excel.ActiveSheet.Range("BB" & i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `RegExp` is not available in Excel VBA by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @wdosanjos - Note that the comment mentions that it requires a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.  If for some reason you wanted to late bind it, you can replace the `New RegExp` call with a call to `CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")`.